# Get numbers from string using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string :

```
 <div id="post_message_957119941">
```

I want to fetch only the numbers (957119941) from this string using `preg_match`.

Comment: Have you tried my regex, did it work for you?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed for 'not a real question'... ah well: preg_match( "/\d+/", "<div id='post_message_957119941'>", $match ) will set $match[ 0 => 957119941 ]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard.

```
$str = '<div id="post_message_957119941">';

if ( preg_match ( '/post_message_([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches ) )
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Output:

`Array ( [0] => post_message_957119941 [1] => 957119941 )`

So the  desired result will always be in: `$matches[1]`

Is that what you need?

Comment: I need multiple string and number then I user
`if ( preg_match ( '/S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+)/', strtoupper($fileName), $matches ) )`
it's work for me