# Selecting two numbers from a string

Tags: php, select

How would I select two numbers from a string, using `preg_match`?
I've used `preg_match` before to select only `<iframe>` and a `#` tag.
For example I need to select the two numbers in an equation:

> "whats 23x347?"
>   And give me an output variable as such:

```
$first_number = 23
$seccond_number = 347

list($first_number, $second_number) = preg_split("/x/",$message);
```

Works however it does not remove the non numerical text before nor after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get numbers from string using preg\_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408673/get-numbers-from-string-using-preg-match)

Comment: Just to recognise `x`? What about `-`, `+`, `/` etc? Or "344sometext654"?

Comment: I already have a script to select the functions such as that. I just need something to select the 1st section of numbers before the 'x' and then to select the 2nd section of numbers after 'x'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it in two ways. preg_split would be easiest but preg_match also works, it's just a little more work.

preg_split

```
$equation = "23x347";
list($first_number, $second_number) = preg_split("/x/",$equation);
print_r(array('first_number' => $first_number, 'second_number' => $second_number));
```

preg_split would return the two values as separate list elements.

```
Array
(
    [first_number] => 23
    [second_number] => 347
)
```

preg_match

```
$equation = "23x347?";
list($first_number, $second_number) = preg_match("/(\d+)x(\d+).*/",$equation);
print_r($matches);
```

preg_match would populate the $matches array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3x347?
    [1] => 23
    [2] => 347
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works so well, the preg_split one.
Just a question I noticed it doesn't separate the last number from text?
Such as if I had 23x347?
it would echo 1st: 23
2nd: 347?

Comment: ah, that can be done but you'd have to use a different regex for that. That wasn't part of the original question so I didn't answer it to do that.

Comment: updated the answer and realized I had bad regex on there at first needed to have the "/(\d+)x(\d+).*/" regex in there vs "/x/". The parenthesis are called capture groups and separate the captured text. The \d+ matches one or more digits and the .* matches anything trailing.

Answer (score 2):

If you match the operator in the middle as a math symbol, you could pass that to another function and then be able to evaluate several expression types: addition, subtration, etc.

Simple preg_match

```
preg_match("/(\d+)\s*?(\*|\.|x|\-|\+|\/|\%|\^)\s*?(\d+)/", $str, $matches)
```

Using the regex in some functions

```
function parseExpression($str='')
{
    if (preg_match("/(\d+)\s*?(\*|\.|x|\-|\+|\/|\%|\^)\s*?(\d+)/", $str, $matches)) {
        $number_1 = $matches[1];
        $operator = $matches[2];
        $number_2 = $matches[3];

        return calculate($number_1, $operator, $number_2);
    }

    return false;
}

function calculate($number_1, $operator, $number_2)
{
    if ($operator === 'x' || $operator === '*' || $operator === '.') {
        return $number_1 * $number_2;
    } elseif ($operator === '-') {
        return $number_1 - $number_2;
    } elseif ($operator === '+') {
        return $number_1 + $number_2;
    } elseif ($operator === '/') {
        return $number_1 / $number_2;
    } elseif ($operator === '%') {
        return $number_1 % $number_2;
    } elseif ($operator === '^') {
        return pow($number_1, $number_2);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

echo var_dump(parseExpression('23x347')); // int(7981)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('8.8')); // int(64)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('23*347')); // int(7981)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('23-347')); // int(-324)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('8/3')); // float(2.6666666666667)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('8%7')); // int(1)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('2^2')); // int(4)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('2 ^ 2')); // int(4), whitespace ok
echo var_dump(parseExpression('')); // bool(false)
echo var_dump(parseExpression()); // bool(false)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('1')); // bool(false)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('0')); // bool(false)
echo var_dump(parseExpression(1)); // bool(false)
echo var_dump(parseExpression('whats 23x347?')); // int(7981)
```

A quick explanation of the regex:

- first parenthesis match and capture one or more digits
- 0 or more spaces, match but no capture
- second parenthesis match and capture one math operator from a list, note the backslash escaping of special characters
- 0 or more spaces, match but no capture
- third parenthesis match and capture one or more digits

The optional space match allows for phrases like "2*2" or "2 * 2"